# Is there a way to import csv files into pandas using values of a dictionary for the name of the dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary

I Just started with python and am currently trying to import multiple csv files as dataframes. While there are some similar questions, they seem not to be helpfull for my problem.
The csv files have the same structure and the names are not how I want them to be when imported as dataframes. A list of dictionaries contains the names of the dataframes (how they should be) together with the names of the csv files.
Since I need to do this multiple times with different folders I tried to create a formula:

```
def import_csv(CSVdict):
    for index in range(len(CSVdict)):
       CSVdict[index]["New_ID"]=pd.read_csv(("C:/path/"+str(CSVdict[index]["csvDatei"])+".csv"),sep=';',decimal=',')
```

I am not sure where my mistake is, Can you help me?
The list of dictionaries looks something like this:

```
[{'Nr': 0905', 'New_ID': '0905a', 'csvDatei': 'LG__380'}, {'Nr': '0905', 'New_ID': '0905b', 'csvDatei': 'LG__376'}, {'Nr': '0955', 'New_ID': '0955a', 'csvDatei': 'LG__53'}, {'Nr': '0955', 'New_ID': '0955b', 'csvDatei': 'LG__50'}]
```

Later on I need to pd.concat() the dataframes with the Same value in Nr. So dataframe with `New_ID =0955a` and `NeW_ID=0955b` and so on need to be in one. Before that they have to be ajusted. So I can't read the file and use pd.concat() directly.

Comment: What is your expected output? What do you mean by dataframe "names" (do you mean dictionary keys)?

Comment: Instead of importing the files like  `0905a=pd.read_csv("C:/path/LG__380.csv", sep=';', decimal=',')` one by one, I want to import them together, but using the values in the dicitonary CSVdict['New_ID'] as the value "name".

Comment: so you want to `pd.concat()` them all, where does the `new_id` value come from?

Comment: I changed the discription to explain the goal with those DataFrames better. I hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the file name as the key, something like:

```py
CSV_dict = [
    {'Nr': '0905', 'New_ID': '0905a', 'csvDatei': 'LG__380'}, 
    {'Nr': '0905', 'New_ID': '0905b', 'csvDatei': 'LG__376'}, 
    {'Nr': '0955', 'New_ID': '0955a', 'csvDatei': 'LG__53'}, 
    {'Nr': '0955', 'New_ID': '0955b', 'csvDatei': 'LG__50'},
]

dataframes = {}
for d in csv_dict:
    path = "C:/path/{}.csv".format(d["csvDatei"])
    dataframes[d["New_ID"]] = pd.read_csv(path, sep=";", decimal=",")
```

If you need to label each DataFrame you can add the following line into the `for` loop:

```py
dataframes[path]["ID_col"] = d["New_ID"]
```

where `d["New_ID"]`  would be the ID applied to each dataframe.

Comment: Thank you! I used you code and got a dictionary of Dataframes. Could you tell me how you would write the for loop, so that the keys in that dictionary would be the value of ``CSV_dict["New_ID"]`` ?

Comment: I've updated the code, on the last line of the `for` loop I've changed `dataframes[path]` for `dataframes[d["New_ID"]]`